# Setting MIN LENGTH in WTFORM attributes

Tags: html, css, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have 3 inputs and a textarea in a `Flask form`. When those are valid I change the CSS with the following code:

```
input:valid ~ label,
textarea:valid ~ label,
input:onfocus ~ label,
textarea:onfocus ~ label
{
    /* Change style */ 
}
```

For the inputs there's no problem because they have the `required` attribute. But the textarea is optional. So all the time is valid and the CSS is applied immediately. I would like to set a `minlength`to the textare so it's only valid when `length < 1`. I tried the following code in the `wtform`but nothing happens.

```
{{ form.textareaName(minlength=1) }}
# I also tried with a String
{{ form.textareaName(minlength="1") }}
```

Some solution? Thanks!

Comment: _nothing happens_ what's the resulting HTML tag for `{{ form.textareaName(minlength=1) }}`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Length validator](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#wtforms.validators.Length) it validates the length of a string. You can set the minimum and maximum length required. i.e.

```
from wtforms.validators import Length
```

In your `forms.py`,

```
textareaName = TextAreaField(validators=[Length(min=2)])
```